# Google Chrome execute HTMLElement.focus before alert get dismissed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, dom-events

It was found that Google Chrome produce different behaviour compared to Firefox and Edge with following snippet:

```js
function lossFocus(e) {
  alert('blur'); // prompt alert
  e.focus();     // focus back to textbox
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onblur="lossFocus(this);" />
<!-- NOTE: You may need to refresh this page after trigger onblur in Chrome to avoid popup loop -->
```

This results `lossFocus` being triggered ad infinitum in Google Chrome as `focus` was executed before user dismiss the popup dialog by pressing OK or with an enter key but it's not the case for other browsers. (Edge managed to focus back the input field after `alert`) What's the reason and is this an expected behaviour?

`window.confirm()` seems promising to execute code after capturing user input, does this means we should stay away from `window.alert()` if we want the code to be executed only after getting user feedback from popup dialog?

Answer (score 0):

No insights yet at this moment but it was found that one of the workaround would be wrapping the culprit with nil timeout like following:

```js
function lossFocus(e) {
  alert('blur');
  setTimeout(() => { e.focus(); }, 0); // focus properly now after dismiss popup
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onblur="lossFocus(this);" />
```